# Usage of BootJar instead of BootRepackage in Gradle as part of Spring Boot Migration from 1..5.x to 2.x

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I am working on Spring Boot migration from 1.5.12 to 2.1.14. We are using Gradle as a build tool, so as part of Spring Boot migration we had to change
Gradle from 3.x to 4.x and trying to update the build.gradle as required. In Spring Boot 2.x migration we have to change the following task in build.gradle

```
task msnServiceBoot(type: BootRepackage, dependsOn:msnJar) {
    println " Executing MsnServiceBoot task"
    mainClassName = 'com.msn.service.MsnApplication'
    customConfiguration = "cloudconfigexclusion"
    withJarTask = msnJar
}
```

In the above code we have to update BootRepackage to BootJar as per the latest Spring documentation.

The error, I'm getting after changing from BootRepackage to BootJar is customConfiguration is unknown property.

May I know how to make customConfiguration for Spring Boot 2.x with gradle 4.x

Comment: Why don;t you move to Gradle 5+?

Comment: Ok @sonus21, I can migrate to gradle 5+, May I know, Is gradle 4.x not compatable with Spring boot 2.x?

Comment: IIRC, there're some changes. In boot 2.x we don't have to do generally packaging unless it's required. There's also a dependency manager tool, that I believe support 5.x only.

Comment: According to the documentation, Spring Boot 2.1.14 requires Gradle 4.4 or later. The newest version of Spring Boot (2.3.1 at this time) requires Gradle 6.3 or later. Also, `customConfiguration` is something from the old 1.x plugin and no longer exists.

Comment: Thanks @BjørnVester for reply. I have the following                               
 configurations {
    cloudconfigexclusion.exclude group: 'org.springframework.cloud', module: 'spring-cloud-config-server'
    cloudconfigexclusion.extendsFrom(compile)
}, So how to replace it in 2.x plugin.

Comment: The error is trying to draw your attention to the fact that there is no such thing as `customConfiguration` in the `BootJar` type. Also last time I used Spring 2, I remember it actually creates a `bootJar` task so maybe you don't even need your `msnServiceBoot` task anymore, and instead just need to configure the existing `bootJar` task. I would suggest you take a look in the [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#building-executable-jars-and-wars)